Convolution with impulse response of damped harmonic oscillator acceleration
To get the way of the mass of a driven damped mass spring system I can convolve the impulse response $g(t)$ of the system with a driving force:
$x(t) = F(t) * g(t)$
This works for me in python using scipy.signal.convolve.
I can also get the speed of the mass by convolving the time derivative of the impulse response with the driving force:
$\dot{x}(t) = F(t) * \dot{g}(t)$
But when I try to get the acceleration of the mass by using the time derivative of the speed impulse response, the result is not correct:
$\ddot{x}(t) \neq F(t) * \ddot{g}(t)$
I checked, that the derivative for the acceleration impulse response is correct.
Both way and speed match my simulation results, but the acceleration does not.
So I think there is a mistake in my way of thinking and that I can't simply get the time derivatives systems output this way.
The code for my experiment:
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate
import scipy.signal

# Mass in kg
m = 12.0
# Spring constant in N/m
k = 10.0
# Damping ration
D = 0.5
# damping coeffiecient
d = D * 2 * np.sqrt(m * k)
# undamped frequency
omega_0 = np.sqrt(k / m)
# Damping value
xi = omega_0 * D
# damped frequency
omega_d = np.sqrt(omega_0**2 - xi**2)


def get_impulse_response_way(t, omega_d, xi, m):

    delta_t = t[1]
    return (1 / omega_d * np.exp(-t * xi) * np.sin(omega_d * t)) * delta_t / m


def get_impulse_response_speed(t, omega_d, xi, m):
    # Impulse response of speed of damped oscillator mass
    # (derivative of way impulse response)
    delta_t = t[1]
    return -np.exp(-xi * t) * (
        xi * np.sin(omega_d * t) - omega_d * np.cos(omega_d * t)
        ) * delta_t / omega_d / m


def get_impulse_response_acc(t, omega_d, xi, m):
    # Impulse response of acceleration of damped oscillator mass
    # (derivative of speed impulse response)
    delta_t = t[1]
    return -np.exp(-xi * t) * (
        (omega_d**2 - xi**2) * np.sin(omega_d * t) +
        2 * xi * omega_d * np.cos(omega_d * t)
        ) / omega_d * delta_t / m


def model(y, t, m, k, d, fex_func):
    ydotdot = (fex_func(t) - d * y[1] - k * y[0]) / m
    return [y[1], ydotdot]

# Simulation timestep
sim_delta_t = 1e-3
# Simulation time
sim_time = np.arange(0, 2000.0, sim_delta_t)
# Time array for impulse response calculation
time_ir = np.arange(0, 1000, sim_delta_t)

# Calculation of impulse responses
ir_way = get_impulse_response_way(time_ir, omega_d, xi, m)
ir_speed = get_impulse_response_speed(time_ir, omega_d, xi, m)
ir_acc = get_impulse_response_acc(time_ir, omega_d, xi, m)

# Driving force function @ 12.5 Hz
fex_func = lambda t: 10.0 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * 12.5 * t)

# Driving force result
fex = fex_func(sim_time)

# Results of convolution of driving force and impulse response
# For way: matches odeint simulation
x_conv_way = scipy.signal.convolve(fex, ir_way)
# For speed: matches odeint simulation
x_conv_speed = scipy.signal.convolve(fex, ir_speed)
# For acceleration: Not matching
x_conv_acc = scipy.signal.convolve(fex, ir_acc)


model_res = scipy.integrate.odeint(model, [0, 0], sim_time,
                                   args=(m, k, d, fex_func))
model_way = model_res[:, 0]
model_speed = model_res[:, 1]
model_acc = (fex_func(sim_time) - d * model_speed - k * model_way) / m

# model_way and x_conv_way do match
# model_speed and x_conv_speed do match
# model_acc and x_conv_acc do NOT match

```

